# Big Theta and linearity

Tags: summation, asymptotics

I have some questions about $\Theta$, when to apply linearity and if it's really possible to apply linearity. I have the following
$$T(n,m) = \sum_{i=1}^n\Theta(m+(i-1)m)$$
I've not proven yet but I know that $\Theta$ could be taken out of the sum and so
$$T(n,m) = \Theta\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n(m+(i-1)m)\bigg)$$
$$= \Theta\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n((i-1+1)m)\bigg)$$
$$= \Theta\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^nim\bigg)$$
$$= \Theta\bigg(m\sum_{i=1}^ni\bigg)$$
And from a well known formula the summation is equal to ${n(n+1)}\over{2}$, and so we can say that
$$T(n,m) = \Theta(n^2m)$$
Which is the right answer... but i was thinking that
$$\Theta\bigg(m\sum_{i=1}^ni\bigg) = \Theta(m(1+2+...+n-1+n)) = \Theta(m+...+(n-1)m+nm))$$
And at this point if the linearity applies since $(n-1)m < nm$, I think that I can say
$$T(n,m) = \Theta(nm)$$
which is wrong, could someone help me understand, thank you.

Comment: $$
T(n,m) \le \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {C_i (m + (i - 1)m)}  \le (\mathop {\max }\limits_i C_i )\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {(m + (i - 1)m)}  = (\mathop {\max }\limits_i C_i )m\frac{{n(n + 1)}}{2}
$$ and similarly in the other direction using $\min$.

Comment: @Gary What is $C_i$?

Comment: It is the implied constant coming from the definition of $\Theta$. $f(n,m)=\Theta(g(n,m,i))$ if there are $c_i,C_i>0$ such that $c_i g(n,m,i)<f(n,m)<C_i g(n,m,i)$ (provided everyone is positive).

Comment: @Gary Oh I see, so in conclusion I can not apply the linearity as I was doing in some of the  last steps, and therefore is wrong to say that given $0 < f(x) < g(x) \forall x \in \mathbb{R},  $ $ \Theta(g(x)+f(x)) = \Theta(g(x))$  right?

Comment: No, that is correct since $$
h(x) = \Theta (f(x) + g(x)) \Rightarrow h(x) \le C(f(x) + g(x)) \le 2Cg(x) \; \text{ and } \; h(x) \ge c(f(x) + g(x)) \ge cg(x)
$$

Comment: @Gary thank you is very clear everything you write to me, but in my mind, since it's true the last thing we said, $\Theta(m+ 2m+ ... + (n-1)m+ nm)$ with $nm$ the greatest of all in the summation, I am inclined to think that  $\Theta(m+ 2m+ ... + (n-1)m+ nm) = \Theta(nm)$ which from the first calculation is not. What am I missing? Thank you

Comment: The problem is that the number of terms depends on $n$. There is no fixed $C$ such that $1 + 2 +  \cdots  + n \le Cn$ for all $n$.